# How to filter an array of objects based of attribute from another object in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-balance',
    templateUrl: './balance.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./balance.component.scss']
})
export class BalanceComponent implements OnInit {

    advertisers: [
{'advertiser_id': 1, 'name': 'foo'},
{'advertiser_id': 2, 'name': 'bar'},
{'advertiser_id': 3, 'name': 'cat'},

];
    balances: [
{'advertiser_id': 1, 'value': '100'},
{'advertiser_id': 2, 'value': '200'},
{'advertiser_id': 3, 'value': '300'},
{'advertiser_id': 3, 'value': '500'},
];

    constructor() {}
}
```

On my template, i'm looping through the balances to display them in a table. I'd like to display the advertiser's name along side the balance row. Therefore, i've tried the following:

```
<div class="card mb-3 shadow-sm">
    <table class="table mb-0">
        <tr>
            <th>Advertiser</th>
            <th class="text-right">Outstanding Balance</th>
            <th class="text-center">Invoices</th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let balance of balances">
            <td class="align-middle">

                <span ng-repeat="advertiser in advertisers | filter : { advertiser_id : balance.advertiser_id }">{{ advertiser.name}}</span>
            </td>
            <td class="align-middle text-right">{{ balance.value }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">New</button>&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Archive</button>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

However, when doing so I get the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

I believe the 'filter' pipe should do the trick, but not sure why it's not working.

Comment: observation: `ng-repeat` is for angularjs, why you trying to use it here? ;)

Comment: @AJT_82 because i'm confused as hell by everything online and the docs mentioned it. Clearly i'm a bit new to Angular and didn't even realise there was a difference.

Comment: https://medium.com/poka-techblog/simplify-your-javascript-use-map-reduce-and-filter-bd02c593cc2d

Comment: Well, the first step is to change `ng-repeat` to `*ngFor`.

Comment: AngularJS and Angular are frameworks that share a common ancestry, but are so different in terms of syntax, semantics and execution that you might think of them as almost completely unrelated. Confusingly, AngularJS was FKA Angular or Angular 1, but now the framework known as 'Angular' is the new version (currently 7.2.4), and the documentation is at [angular.io](https://angular.io). You've tagged this question 'angular' which refers to the new version, but used AngularJS constructs in your code.

Comment: @JohnDibling Thanks for the detailed clarification.

Comment: So are you intending to use AngularJS or Angular (new version)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a pipe.

```
@Pipe({
   name: 'myFilterPipe'
})
export class MyFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(advertisers: any[], advertiser_id: any): any[] {
         return (advertisers || []).filter(advertiser => advertiser.advertiser_id===advertiser_id) 
    }
}
```

and then replace

```
 <span ng-repeat="advertiser in advertisers | filter : { advertiser_id : balance.advertiser_id }">{{ advertiser.name}}</span>
```

with

```
<span *ngFor="let advertiser of advertisers | myFilterPipe: balance.advertiser_id">{{ advertiser.name}}</span>
```

Or you can transform data before rendering (much better)

```
private balances: BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]); 
private advertisers: BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]); 

data$: Observable<any[]> = combineLatest(this.balances.asObservable(), this.advertisers.asObservable()).pipe(
    map([balances,advertisers] => {
        return balances.map(balance => {
            balance.advertisers = advertisers.filter(advertiser=>advertiser.advertiser_id===balance.advertiser_id);
            return balance;
        })
    })
)
```

and then

```
<tr *ngFor="let balance of data$ | async">
    <td class="align-middle">
        <span *ngFor="let advertiser of balance.advertisers">{{ advertiser.name}}</span>
    </td>
    <td class="align-middle text-right">{{ balance.value }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">New</button>&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Archive</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```